# how to import export docker compose?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am still new in docker and all container things.
I have server with full access at 
1.1.1.1 and I installed docker there. (without docker compose)
In the other place my friend have server 2.2.2.2 and he installed docker and docker compose there.

At 2.2.2.2 server, my friend build 3 container : container A (Git), container B(unknown), container C(unknown). 
I can access content of container A (Git) with browsers.

My question is: can I import container A to my server in 1.1.1.1? I have user access to download Git, but what I want is to import the container, not Git (content inside the container).
Any hint? what should I do? Or it is impossible to do if I don't have access to the command console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to move the running container instance then I would recommend you to run the below command

```
$ docker ps
 CONTAINER ID    IMAGE             COMMAND       CREATED       STATUS       NAMES
 c3f279d17e0a   ubuntu:12.04      /bin/bash      7 days ago    Up 25 hours desperate_dubinsky
 197387f1b436   ubuntu:12.04      /bin/bash      7 days ago    Up 25 hours focused_hamilton

$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3
```

This would create the image on the host machine and then run the below command to save the image as tar file to upload it into another host.

```
$ docker save -o testimage.tar svendowideit/testimage:version3
```

On scp the tar image to another host run the below command to extract the tar and save it as docker images.

```
 $ docker images
 REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

 $ docker load --input testimage.tar
 Loaded image: svendowideit/testimage:version3

 $ docker images
 REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
 svendowideit/testimage version3            769b9341d937        7 weeks ago         2.489 MB
```

Now you can make use of docker run command to bring up the docker instance of the saved images.

Comment: Dear @Viswesn thank you very much. That was very helpful. Thank you for your guidance. Some additional question, if I want to save docker image, should I stop the docker service? If ok when docker running, it will give impact for people who used it? (for example become slow or something?)

Comment: We can safely run Docker save without stopping the Docker but make sure the new docker comes up with new mounted volumes or environment; For example you did Docker save on MySQL DB then MySQL data should be mounted in host machine; For new Docker that is going to come up with MySQL should make use of new volume directory so it will create things from scratch. So it depends on what it is and how you are planning to delpoy your IaaS.

Comment: Got it... Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

A running container can be exported into a tar archive which can be copied to a different machine and them be imported back.

On the machine where the container is running, do the following:

```
docker export --output "A.tar" <container-A>
```

Next copy the generated archive A.tar to your machine, and import it:

```
docker import A.tar <container-A-image>
```

This will create an image on your machine which can be then started using `docker run ...`

Comment: Dear @yamenk Thank you very much. If I do export in container A, should I stop the docker service? Or it is possible to export even docker is running?

Comment: The container can be running when exporting. No need to stop the service.

Comment: Hi @yamenk would this be a good way to backup docker containers? For example export them all to an external drives and then should the main drive fail they can be imported back in?

Answer (score -1):

No. If you would like to have had the image, which is used to run the container A(Git), then your friend has to push the Docker image to a Docker registry. This will give you the possibility to run the same Docker image as Docker container on your server. But not the data.

Docker images are by design immutable. Started Docker Images are called Docker Containers. Basically this Docker containers are completely deleted if you stop and remove them. If you have data you would like to persists, then you can use so called `bind volumes`, for example.

You see, your question is very broad. And there are ways to achieve what you want, but I can only point you to some documentation to go further. Or you can join a local meetup, which would be the fastes way to come aboard.

https://www.slideshare.net/Docker/introduction-to-docker-2017

https://docs.docker.com/

https://events.docker.com/

Comment: Dear @kleinsasserm
Thank you very much for your insight.
Understood. As I thought from search and learn, it impossible if my friend not push or share the image.
Thank you very much.